# datetime.tostring month and day language

Tags: c#, datetime, tostring, cultureinfo

i have a list of email addresses of people that have different nationalities (for each person i have the iso code)

when i send the email to all these people, in the text of the mail i need to to convert a datetime field to a string formatted in their specific culture.

for this i'm doing

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(ISO);
myStringDate = myDate.ToString(ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
```

and work perfect, but if i use LongDatePattern instead short, for displaying date like "Monday, 13 June 2010" its work fine except the language of the day and month.

if the person culture is it-IT i need to display "Martedi" and "Giugno" not "monday" and "June"

how can i do that without change the current UI culture?

Answer (score 25):

Those patterns describe year, month, day and other parameter **locations** in the output result of `DateTime`. But month and day **names** are taken from the `CultureInfo` object, not pattern. There's the [`DateTime.ToString()` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring) that supports passing the `CultureInfo` parameter along with the format.

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(ISO); 
DateTime.Now.ToString(culture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern, culture);
```

This way, `.ToString()` will respect both pattern and names from specified culture

Answer (score 13):

You have only specified the format pattern, so it takes the other settings from the default format. You should also specify the format provider:

```
myStringDate = myDate.ToString(ci.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern, ci);
```

or using the standard format string `D` for long date pattern (as it will take the actual pattern from the format provider that you specify):

```
myStringDate = myDate.ToString("D", ci);
```

---

Demo:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("it-IT");
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("D", ci));
ci = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("D", ci));
```

Output:

```
giovedì 26 gennaio 2012
den 26 januari 2012
```

Answer (score 7):

I just had a similar problem and solved it with:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("it-IT"));
```

That was thanks to [this link.](http://forums.asp.net/t/1087778.aspx?How%20can%20I%20change%20DayOfWeek%20to%20French%20)

Comment: simplest solution imo ty

Answer (score 4):

Use `DateTimeFormatInfo` class.

```
string code = "mk-MK";
DateTimeFormatInfo info =
    DateTimeFormatInfo.GetInstance(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(code));
string longDate = 
    DateTime.Now.ToString(info.LongDatePattern, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(code));
```

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime.ToString()` has yet another overload with which you can specify both the pattern you want (as you are currently *and* the culture to use. Try:

```
myStringDate = myDate.ToString(ci.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern,
                               ci);
```