# Change Month name (Other language) in DateTime format dd/MMM/yyyy

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a dateTime field with the format `dd/MMM/yyyy` (05/NOV/2013). I want to change the "**NOV**" in some other language (e.g: Arabic). **How can I convert it**?

**Edit:** Sorry for not providing the code, here it is.

**C# Code:**

```
string tempGrgDt = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy"));
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. `DateTime` itself doesn't have a format - you format it however you want to. It would be really helpful if you could provide code...

Comment: Do you mean you want something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9022326/2258

Answer (score 10):

You just need this

```
var date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy",new CultureInfo("ar"));
```

Prints

> 02/محرم/1435

You need to pass the `CultureInfo` while converting DateTime to String. You'll get localized string in the given culture.

**Update**:
If you have three letter month in english and you need to convert to arabic month you can do this

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("NOV", "MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string arabicMonth = new CultureInfo("ar").DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(dt.Month);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this was not my exact answer to my question. I didn't asked for the localize of whole date. I want just to replace NOV by some Arabic text like يناير

Comment: Then change the formatting string from "dd/MMM/yyyy" to whatever suits your fancy.  That is the correct Arabic, right?

Comment: Yes, but it changes the whole Gregorian date to Hijri date. I am asking that is there a way to edit the text of NOV in dd/MMM/yyyy to some text?

Comment: This answer will give you what you want, not sure what the problem is?