# how to specify month's language (CultureInfo) in Lotusscript Format (now, "dd/mmm/yyyy")

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, date-formatting, regional-settings

This question is the LOTUSCRIPT version of 
[datetime.tostring month and day language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022100/datetime-tostring-month-and-day-language/9022326#9022326)

*Need description*:
I need a string date in the dd/mmm/yyyy format (ex: "28 feb 2014"). I don't want english (intl) language for this 3 letters, and **not** the default regional setting in use in the LOCAL client.

*Constraints*:

1. Programmatic language used: Lotusscript on client side in Lotus Notes.
2. I can't change the regional setting of the client computer. Barely acceptable a **specific to Lotus Notes** registry is painful (like: http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tip/Resolve-Domino-date-format-problems-for-dd-mm-yyyy-format)

I guess format$ will not solve my problem. What can I use ? My last resort will be select case month(now) case 1: resu = resu + " jan " ....

Any better idea ? Thanks in advance for a such "deja vu" topic.

[Edited I wrote previously "I wan't English" when it should be "I **don't** want". Format in LS ALWAYS returns english ]

Comment: I will need some time to check, then I will mark one of the response a accepted answer, Thanks for your response it really helped!
NB I feell nempoBu4 respected exactly the question, but Phil Jones is elegant. It's an honor to have to decide between the 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Windows you can use WinApi [`GetDateFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318086%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. For this function you need to create [`SYSTEMTIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure. Also you need to use [`Language Identifier Constants and Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318693%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`Day, Month, Year, and Era Format Pictures`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317787%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) topics for setting language and format of date and time.
Here is example:

```vb
'Declarations
Type SYSTEMTIME
    wYear As Integer
    wMonth As Integer
    wDayOfWeek As Integer
    wDay As Integer
    wHour As Integer
    wMinute As Integer
    wSecond As Integer
    wMilliseconds As Integer
End Type

Declare Function GetDateFormat Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetDateFormatA" (_
Byval Locale As Long,_
Byval dwFlags As Long,_
lpDate As SYSTEMTIME,_
Byval lpFormat As String,_
Byval lpDateStr As String,_
Byval cchDate As Long) As Long

Function FormatDate(value As Variant, locale As Long, formatString As String) As String

    Dim buffer As String, systemTime As SYSTEMTIME

    systemTime.wYear = Year(value)
    systemTime.wMonth = Month(value)
    systemTime.wDay = Day(value)

    buffer = String(255, 0)

    GetDateFormat locale&, 0, systemTime, formatString$ , buffer, Len(buffer)

    FormatDate$ = Left$(buffer, Instr(1, buffer, Chr$(0)) - 1)

End Function

'Usage
MessageBox FormatDate(Now, &h40c, "dd MMM yyyy")
'&h40c - is fr-FR locale (0x040c)
```

Another way is to use LS2J. For this you can use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class and its [`format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29) method. Also you need to use [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) class and [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class for setting language and date.
Here is example:

```vb
'Declarations
Uselsx "*javacon"'Include this for using Java objects in LotusScript

Function FormatDate(value As Variant, language As String, country As String, formatString As String) As String

    Dim javaSession As New JavaSession

    Dim localeClass As JavaClass
    Dim locale As JavaObject

    Dim calendarClass As JavaClass
    Dim calendar As JavaObject

    Dim dateFormatClass As JavaClass
    Dim dateFormat As JavaObject

    Set localeClass = javaSession.GetClass("java/util/Locale")
    Set locale = localeClass.CreateObject("(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V", language$, country$)

    Set calendarClass = javaSession.GetClass("java/util/Calendar")
    Set calendar = calendarClass.GetMethod("getInstance", "()Ljava/util/Calendar;").Invoke()
    'You need to subtract 1 from month value
    Call calendar.set(Year(value), Month(value) - 1, Day(value))

    Set dateFormatClass = javaSession.GetClass("java/text/SimpleDateFormat")
    Set dateFormat = dateFormatClass.CreateObject("(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Locale;)V", formatString$, locale)

    FormatDate$ = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime())

End Function

'Usage
MessageBox FormatDate(Now, "fr", "FR", "dd MMM yyyy")
```

In this example I have used [this constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#Locale%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)  for getting `Locale` object. You can get language codes from [here](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) and country codes from [here](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/).
For `SimpleDateFormat` object I have used [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29) constructor.

Comment: Both solutions are corresponding to my need, I will check them ! Thanks

Comment: wow! I was finding the API approach a bit to heavy for this need... with aLS2J approach you cover all the scopes! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Specifing a language in the form / Script library doesn't influence the Format result.

The java works specifying the langage (attention: limited choice!)

The kernel32 accepts a langage as you mentioned &h409 - is en-US locale (0x0409) the whole list could be found at http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/25B6B398/5BB4C48A

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `Format(Now, "dd mmm yyyy")` will produce the month in English, but I'm not 100% certain.

If not, you could use

`Day(Now) & " " & Mid("JanFebMarAprMayJulJunAugSepOctNovDec", 3* Month(Now) -2, 3) & " " & Year(Now)`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(3 * (Month(Now) - 1)+1)` or `3 * Month(Now) - 2` ?

Comment: Torsten, you're absolutely right - I've edited my post to correct that, thanks.

Comment: I love the tiny written with mid which is really shorter than a select case!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a better way than to manually construct the date string in your own function:

```
Function FormatDate(sourceDate as Variant) As String

    Dim months[1 to 12] as String
    months[1] = "Jan"
    months[2] = "Feb"
    months[3] = "Mar"
    months[4] = "Apr"
    months[5] = "May"
    months[6] = "Jun"
    months[7] = "Jul"
    months[8] = "Aug"
    months[9] = "Sep"
    months[10] = "Oct"
    months[11] = "Nov"
    months[12] = "Dec"

    Dim monthPart as String
    Dim dayPart as String
    Dim yearPart as String

    dayPart = Format(sourceDate, "dd")
    yearPart = Format(sourceDate, "yyyy")
    monthPart = months[Month(sourceDate)]

    FormatDate = dayPart & " " & monthPart & " " & yearPart

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, this is an alternative to the select case I intended to use, but I prefer the tiny writing Phil suggested.